# How to make sure all keys in dictionnary are initalized

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting a bunch of strings from an API call on my application start. I store them in a dictionnary into a singleton so I can reuse them through my app.

The problem is that the call is finished and the completion is fired before all keys are initialized in my dictionnary. What would be the method to wait for all of them to be initialized so it's not returning nil ?

Here is my initialization method :

```
    func setLocales(locales: Layout, success: ([String: String]) -> Void) {
        self.layout["infoAllDebates"] = locales.infoAllDebates ?? "Débats"
        self.layout["actionReadMore"] = locales.actionReadMore ?? "Lire plus"
        self.layout["actionSeeMore"] = locales.actionSeeMore ?? "Voir plus"
        self.layout["actionAddArgument"] = locales.actionAddArgument ?? "Ajouter un argument"
        self.layout["actionLinkToDebate"] = locales.actionLinkToDebate ?? "Aller au débat"
        self.layout["actionUpdate"] = locales.actionUpdate ?? "Modifier"
        .... (150 more lines of strings)
        success(self.layout)
    }
```

The completion (success() here) is firing but when I call one of the keys in a view it is not initialized yet so I get an error about this key being nil.

The API call looks like this :

```
func getSettings(completion: (() -> Void)?) -> () {
        apiClient.getSettings { settings in
            self.setLocales(locales: settings.data.resource.layout, success: { layout in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if completion != nil {
                        return completion!()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

What should I do to ensure that all the keys are initialized ?

Comment: Use a Codable struct rather than dictionary. A dictionary has an unlimited number of keys, so you cannot assure they're all initialized. A struct has a specific number of keys, so you can.

Comment: OK that seems to be a good advice. But would I be able to check anyway ?

Comment: With a struct, the compiler will check for you. You won't be able to return from `init` without setting everything.

Comment: Are you sure that you use the completion functionality correctly? It sounds like an asynchronous issue.

Comment: @vadian I'm not sure

Comment: A completion handler In the `setLocales` function makes no sense because everything is synchronous. Please add the code of the API call and how/when you try to get the values.

Comment: @vadian I edited it so you can see the API call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove the completion handler in `setLocales` because everything is synchronous

```
func setLocales(locales: Layout) {
    self.layout["infoAllDebates"] = locales.infoAllDebates ?? "Débats"
    self.layout["actionReadMore"] = locales.actionReadMore ?? "Lire plus"
    self.layout["actionSeeMore"] = locales.actionSeeMore ?? "Voir plus"
    self.layout["actionAddArgument"] = locales.actionAddArgument ?? "Ajouter un argument"
    self.layout["actionLinkToDebate"] = locales.actionLinkToDebate ?? "Aller au débat"
    self.layout["actionUpdate"] = locales.actionUpdate ?? "Modifier"
    .... (150 more lines of strings)
}
```

Second of all don't **return** the (first) completion handler, **call** it

```
func getSettings(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    apiClient.getSettings { settings in
        self.setLocales(locales: settings.data.resource.layout)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           completion?() // The completion != nil check is "unswifty"
        }
    }
}
```

Side note: Avoid the `get` and `set` prefixes if you interact with Objective-C. This could cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your solution and your clear explanations. Anyway I'm still getting a nil value when I call for a specific key.

Comment: Then the problem is in the context where you use `getSettings`